# ms access pivot column names

Tags: ms-access

Hello I have a sql statement which creates a crosstab in access, it works good however I want the columns to be in a different order.  They show up in alphabetic order I want them to show up based on the order of a different filed.  That is how can i do this;

PIVOT RoleTable.Role_Descr IN(SELECT Role_Descr From RoleNames order by displayorder);

I did some research and found that in the IN clause I would have to list all the column Names manually.  Is this correct

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to list all columns, Furthermore, if you list a column for which there is no data, it will still show in the crosstab and if you miss listing a column that has data, it will not be included in the crosstab.